# Resolve incompatible types without casting in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type (GenericType) which has a property (prop) which can contain one of two values ("thing1" | "thing2").

I also have a type (Thing1Type) in which "prop" is always "thing1". I want to check if prop = "thing1" then call a method that expects that type signature. I could cast "GenericType" to "Thing1Type", but I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this without casting?

Example Code:

```
type GenericType = {
  prop: "thing1" | "thing2"
};

type Thing1Type = {
  prop: "thing1";
};

const myObj: GenericType = { prop: "thing1" };

const myMethod = (obj: Thing1Type) => {
  console.log(obj);
}

if (myObj.prop == "thing1") {
  myMethod(myObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need a type guard like this:

```
function hasThing1(obj: GenericType): obj is {prop:"thing1"}
{
    return obj?.prop === "thing1"
}
```

And then you can safely call your function :

```
if(hasThing1(myObj)){
    myMethod(myObj)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgFXNAvFA3gFBRRhID2YAXFAETAAWK8A5gIy1QA+djzLAJlqEAvgG5ChUJCgYmrNlhl4iJMpRr157WhPGS05eAGdgUALYgA8gCMAVjTiJUmbFBWkK1Xto5R9hIYmZpYAshCM5AAm7lAAFOT2NHL8itgAlO4AfATEUEHG5AA2EAB0ReQsCfbpepIoAGZxDACGxikKcZa2dunpqiQWIOGRUV3WNaKShA0ArvBowChGUK3tvtUOsAjI6EoQ6TSJdlAoxgTq1FqptCKEAyRIEbNI8FDHAPyll+44eNcKXSiIA)

Comment: You can [avoid using any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgFXNAvFA3gFBRRhID2YAXFAETAAWK8A5gIy1QA+djzLAJlqEAvgG5ChUJCgYmrNlhl4iJMpRr157WhPGS05eAGdgUALYgA8gCMAVjTiJUmbFBWkK1Xto5R9hIYmZpYAshCM5AAm7lAAFOT2NHL8itgAlO4AfATEUEHG5AA2EAB0ReQsCfbpepIoAGZxDACGxikKcZa2dunpqiQWIOGRUV3WNaKShA0ArvBowChGUK3tvtUOUPMA1vDkAO7w6TSJdlAoxgTq1FqptCKEAyRIEbNI8PFnUG3XXjSmVCsETpUo3dw4PB3BTCERAA) if your linter is mad at you :)

Comment: I guess we should also absolutely check if `obj` isn't `null` or `undefined`...

Comment: Updated with your suggestions except for the `unknown` part. It would cause other exceptions.